# How do you set up your health in D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, hit-points

I'm setting up my D&D character and I don't actually have the D&D 3.5 edition handbook. I am also new to the D&D world so I'm kind of a noob. How do you set up health for a Half-elf Sorcerer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the tour! The tendency is toward jargon, so if I can rephrase the question a little, it sounds like you're creating a *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* character without a *Player's Handbook*, and you need to determine your character's hit points. Is that accurate? Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Yes, it is accurate as I said I am a bit of a noob so I don't know much.

Comment: There is no way you're going to be able to play D&D 3.5 if you have zero knowledge of the game, no access to the book and have to rely on RPG stackexchange to help you through every aspect of character creation. I'd highly suggest asking your DM to teach you the game, or to get the book and to learn it yourself.

Comment: I already have my character mostly done I just don't know what to do for figuring out how much health I will have. I already know my hit dice. it is 1d6.

Comment: @scratchy151002 My bad for my former comment, I didn't know that information was purposefully left out in most documentation. While I think I remember finding it online, it was not as easy as I thought, hence a misplaced comment, in hindsight.

Answer (score 10):

Learning to play the game without the *Player’s Handbook* is (intentionally) difficult, and generally speaking most would recommend only trying to do so with the assistance of someone who has played before—and who probably has the book.

Anyway, most of the *rules* are found in the System Reference Document, or SRD, which Wizards of the Coast released under the Open Game License and so can be found on a lot of websites, like [this one](http://www.d20srd.org/index.htm). As the name says, it’s meant to be a “reference” for players and DMs, and not wholly replace the books. While it has most of the rules, it’s missing some crucial ones—like how leveling up works, including your 1st level—and beyond that it’s missing all the help and guidance that the book provides to make it more accessible.

So, for example, the rules [explain what hit points are, and how you lose them, and what happens when you run out](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/injuryandDeath.htm), but how you actually get them to begin with is left out. The rules [also say](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/multiclass.htm) “A character gains hit points from each class as his or her class level increases, adding the new hit points to the previous total,” but does not describe *how many* hit points a character gains. And unless you already knew what it was talking about, [this rule about adding Con to hit dice](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#constitutionCon) probably doesn’t mean much to you—you wouldn’t know that it had anything to do with hp.

And I can tell you that the way it works is that every class offers a “hit die” at each level, for example [the barbarian’s d12](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm), and that each time you level up you increase your hp by rolling the hit die and adding your Constitution modifier to it, so a level of barbarian might grant you 1d12+4 hp if you had 18 Constitution. Rolling a 7 on the d12 results in a total of 11 hp gained for that level of barbarian. I could also point out that your first level, the hit die is maximized (so just 12+4, not 1d12+4, for that barbarian’s 1st level), and that many tables replace rolling a hit die with some other method (often, using its average).

From all that, you might be able to synthesize enough to figure out your character’s hp: you have to look up your class’s hit die, add your Constitution modifier to that to get your starting hp, and then for each level after 1st, you have to roll the hit die and add the Constitution modifier again. And that will cover hp as far as it goes, assuming you don’t get into more complicated situations.

But even if you get all that, the *Player’s Handbook* walks you through it. A friend who is familiar with the game can be even better, walking you through it **and** answering questions. Going with *just* the SRD, supplemented with a few questions here, is going to be real rough going. Because there will be more questions—hp is not the only thing that the SRD leaves out. I strongly recommend finding better resources, even if it’s just [one of the discussion forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563) so you can actually talk with players. The Q&A format does not work well for these kinds of basic questions, and users here often will not want to spend the time to “read the book to you.” The only reason I am here is for the sake of explaining why going without the book (or a friend) is going to be hard.

Comment: Uh, the SRD doesn't state how you get your starting point? I know I found it *somewhere* on the Internet, but I'd have thought the information to be more readily available.

Comment: @Nyakouai No, that’s intentionally left out as part of an effort to make sure the SRD could not replace the books. Doesn’t stop people from talking about it, of course.

Comment: @Nyakouai the SRD only includes open game content. WOTC did *not* release character creation or advancement rules as open game content. All the XP rules and similar are not legally reproduceable. (Easy to forget, because they released nearly everything else).

Comment: @fectin-freeMonica Yeah, plus the fact that you are familiar with those rules once you played a little - that seems the most basic of all. People tend to forget (at least I do), that things they know from the top of their heads might not be as obvious to someone else. Thanks for the reminder :)